# Hebrew directional "bug"

Tags: support, hebrew

I know right to left languages are hard to accommodate in left to right processors, but I found an error in the one SE uses.

If you are scrolling through a chunk of Hebrew text, pressing the left arrow key moves to the left.  However, if you hold shift to select text, pressing the left arrow key selects text to the right.  Which is annoying if you are trying to selectively highlight text to make corrections while scrolling through to have to keep changing directional keys.

Is this something easily fixable?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Stack Exchange: the same is true elsewhere. It's a bug (or feature) in some other program of yours (and mine), though I don't know whether it's the browser or the OS or what.

Comment: @msh210 Ya - I said it was the "one SE uses" but I just wasn't sure if it's something they can do anything about.  They are programming wizards, after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vagaries of [BIDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-directional_text)... and the [Unicode BIDI algorithm](http://www.w3.org/International/articles/inline-bidi-markup/uba-basics) implemented by different browsers and operating systems.

That such behaviour occurs depends on a few different factors, some of which are - what browser one uses, what operating system and what is present in the text - does it contain [rlm/lrm](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H34.html)  marks, is there any use of the [dir attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/dirlang.html#h-8.2) and more.

Unfortunately, not something under our control - nothing much we can do about it.

I too suffer from this, as a native Hebrew speaker...

Comment: Tips: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/111